# What is the most efficient way to loop through column-specific calculations for a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

Let me start out by saying I am VERY new to programming. I am trying to learn, but there is still quite a bit that is opaque to me...

What I have is a dataframe of variables, 4  columns and 22 rows, containing constants I would like to use, depending on the situation... the "situation" in this case being another dramaframe, now blank, with 15 columns and 11 rows. I attached a photo of what I mean.

The columns S, C, P, R, and I use the same values from the table containing alpha, beta, delta, and gamma in a calculation (i.e. alpha * Q**beta) Where S needs these values from the 4th row (so alpha[4] * Q ** beta[4] would be needed for all "S" columns, while "c" needs alpha[3] * Q**beta[3]). I would like to know the best way to loop through the calculations, assigning the different alpha and beta values to the appropriate columns in a loop.

The tables are 2D arrays, but the columns will repeat themselves twiceover, giving three sets of 5 columns. All the S columns will be identical, as well as the C, P, R, I columns will be identical to each other.

[this is the dataframe with values I would like to use for calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z86tD.png)

[this is the dataframe I would like to contain all the calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRVHp.png)

What I am trying to do is perform the same calculations to the entire dataframe, but the constants must change depending on which column it is. What I mean is this: for each of the "S" columns I would like the value to be alpha[4]*(Q**beta[4]), for each of the "C" columns I would like the value to be alpha[3]*(Q**beta[3]), so on and so forth. It also needs to be in a loop form, because "Q" increases with each iteration down the dramaframe. To further complicate things, this intervale Q increases by is not a constant. for the first 6 rows, Q must increase by 'j1', but in the last 6 rows, it must increase by 'j2'.

I am thus seeing lots of nested loops being the solution, but each time I go in, it calculates only part of the dataframe, or none of it at all.

I tried... this...

```py
for n in range (11):
    for col in df_26:
        if n <= 6:
            if 'S' in col:
                Q1 = 0.0005
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[4] * (Q1**beta[4])
                    Q1 = Q1 + j1
            elif "C" in col:
                Q1 = 0.0005
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[3] * (Q1**beta[3])
                    Q1 = Q1 + j1
            elif 'P' in col:
                Q1 = 0.0005
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[2] * (Q1**beta[2])
                    Q1 = Q1 + j1
            elif "R" in col:
                Q1 = 0.0005
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[1] * (Q1**beta[1])
                    Q1 = Q1 + j1
            else:
                Q1 = 0.0005
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[0] * (Q1**beta[0])
                    Q1 = Q1 + j1
        else: 
            if 'S' in col:
                Q2 = 0.015
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[4] * (Q2**beta[4])
                    Q2 = Q2 + j2
            elif "C" in col:
                Q2 = 0.015
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[3] * (Q2**beta[3])
                    Q2 = Q2 + j2
            elif 'P' in col:
                Q2 = 0.015
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[2] * (Q2**beta[2])
                    Q2 = Q2 + j2
            elif "R" in col:
                Q2 = 0.015
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[1] * (Q2**beta[1])
                    Q2 = Q2 + j2
            else:
                Q2 = 0.015
                for i, row_value in df_26_1_mass[col].iteritems():
                    df_26[col][i] = alpha[0] * (Q2**beta[0])
                    Q2 = Q2 + j2
```

[This is what I got, indicating I am severly misunderstanding how to structure the loop and get what I want...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChJsD.png)

I really hope I was clear. I need help. Oh boy, yes I feel I must be missing something very important to help get this correct. The middle columns seem to be giving me more reasonable results, but the "s" and "i" are obviously, totally wrong. Can you help steer me in the right direction? Thank you all so much!!

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the algorithm is, making it hard to answer your question. Is this a multidimensional data set flattened into a 2D table? What is the meaning of `S1` and `S2` exactly?

I ask this because there might be a better way to organize your data such that it makes this easier to comprehend.

Also, please define what you mean by 'most efficient way to loop' - this can mean a lot of things... if you are just searching for a general 'how to' I would avoid using the term 'most efficient'.

If this is pandas related, add a pandas tag as well.

Comment: @Scott thank you for your feedback... I edited my post. I hope it adds some clarity. I'm sorry it's still rather hard to communicate all these concepts when they are still so new to me, I really appreciate your patience. Hopefully I made things more clear now.